# In a group G, $a^2b^2=b^2a^2$ and $a^3b^3=b^3a^3$ hold for all $a,b\in G$. Prove that the group is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

> In a group G, $a^2b^2=b^2a^2$ and $a^3b^3=b^3a^3$ hold for all $a,b\in G$. Prove that the group is abelian.

How to solve this problem. The problem is that I am not able to use cancellation law. Don't know how to solve.

Edit

There is an answer in [Prove that the group $G$ is abelian if $a^2 b^2 = b^2 a^2$ and $a^3 b^3 = b^3 a^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423870/prove-that-the-group-g-is-abelian-if-a2-b2-b2-a2-and-a3-b3-b3-a?rq=1)

I need a simple technique to solve it rather than using the concept of $Z(G)$. Please help.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks. I have edited. I want to use the technique by user210387. I request for a detailed solution, if possible.